# How to make an immutable readonly property in the header file (.h), a mutable readwrite property in implementaion (.m)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an object that holds a dictionary `JSONData`. From the header file, and to the other classes that'll access it, I want this property to only be read-only and immutable.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *JSONData;

@end
```

However, I need it to be `readwrite` and mutable from the implementation file, like this, but this doesn't work:

```
@interface MyObject ()

@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *JSONData;

@end

@implementation MyObject

// Do read/write stuff here.

@end
```

Is there anything I can do to enforce the kind of abstraction I'm going for? I looked at the other questions and while I already know how to make a property `readonly` from `.h` and `readwrite` from `.m`, I can't find anything about the difference in mutability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a separate private mutable variable in your implementation. You can override the getter to return an immutable object.

```
@interface MyObject () {
  NSMutableDictionary *_mutableJSONData;
}
@end

@implementation MyObject 

// ...

-(NSDictionary *)JSONData {
   return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:_mutableJSONData];
}

// ...
@end
```

No need to implement the setter, as it is `readonly`.

Comment: Yup, I actually just found my own way to this solution too. NOTE: **DO NOT** use `self.rawData[@"key"] = @"value"` anywhere in the implementation because it won't work. `_rawData[@"key"] = @"value"`, however, will, because you're accessing the instance variable instead of the property (declared immutable). Do I really need to override the getter though?

Comment: Yes. You are returning a different class of object.

Comment: ^Ah, right. If I'm not mistaken, the compiler won't complain, but if I don't override the getter, it will return an `NSMutableDictionary` instance with the modifier methods inaccessible.

Comment: Note that you can no longer use KVO on JSONData if you do this.

Comment: Good point. On the basis of the level of the question, though, I think that was not to be expected.

Comment: @MattQuiros, if you want property access in implementation (i.e. `self.rawData`) look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10540765).

Comment: That's essentially the same as mine, only less simple. My `()` indicates also a category.